# Indexing based on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I'm new to python and below mentioned is an ongoing data engineering issue I'm currently trying to resolve.

#### Table structure

[image: Table structure:]

### Data:

##### Index 1 :

Is sequential and would increment by 1 as rows are added.

##### Index 2 : The problem <<-- To tabulate index 2

This is dependent on values stored in the columns [A,B,C,D,E]. If the value remains the same, we need to assign a single index for these rows.

*eg: Rows 1,2,3 have *567* as a value for A,B,C respectively.
Therefore, index 2 is 100 for these 3 rows.*

#### Record types :

- 1 - A
- 2 - B
- 3 - C
- 4 - D
- 5 - E

#### Code

```
data =  [(100, 100, 1 , 567,'','','','') ,
         (101, 100, 2 , '',567,'','','') ,
         (102, 100, 3 , '','',567,'','') ,
         (103, 101, 3 , '','',568,'','') ,
         (104, 101, 4 , '','','',568,'') ,
         (105, 101, 5 , '','','','',568) ]  

#Creates the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns = ['index1' , 'index2', 'record_type' , 'A','B','C','D','E'], dtype=str)

#Combines columns A,B,C,D,E and adds a $ where ever it is null in order to stack these values 
df['combined'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C','D','E']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg('$'.join)

# Cleans the column 'combined'
df['combined_cleaned']= df['combined'].replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
```

Attempting to use the combined_cleaned column to calculate index2.
Not sure if this is the right approach, open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: A couple of clarification questions.  (1) are the number of columns used for the computation always the same and are they always labeled "A thru E"?  (2) What happens if the value 567 appears later in the dataframe (e.g. index1 = 109, column D = 567?

Comment: `df[list('ABCDE')].T.agg(''.join).factorize()[0] + 100` should suffice

Comment: @itprorh66 Answers to your questions:
1) The total number of columns  = 6: This is fixed.
2) If column D or E has 567, the index2 value would be 100

Basically, we can only have a single value in columns A through E in a single row.
Therefore, if 567 appears in column D, that would be a new row with an index1 value of 106 and an index2 value of 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few assumptions here, but seem to fit your problem.

If there is only ever 1 value over those columns for each row then you can take the `max` along the row, and then find consecutive groups checking whether that Series is equal to itself, shifted.

We add 99 because by definition the counting will start at 1, but you seem to want 100.

```
val_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
s = df[val_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric).max(1)
#0    567.0
#1    567.0
#2    567.0
#3    568.0
#4    568.0
#5    568.0
#dtype: float64

df['index2'] = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum() + 99
```

---

```
print(df)
  index1 record_type    A    B    C    D    E  index2
0    100           1  567                         100
1    101           2       567                    100
2    102           3            567               100
3    103           3            568               101
4    104           4                 568          101
5    105           5                      568     101
```

---

If instead of a single value, `'record_type'` points to the appropriate column you can use numpy indexing.

```
import numpy as np

arr = df[val_cols].to_numpy()
idx = df['record_type'].astype(int).to_numpy()

vals = arr[np.arange(len(arr)), idx-1]
#array(['567', '567', '567', '568', '568', '568'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `combined_cleaned` column could be generated directly using

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E']
df[cols].replace('', np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().item(), axis=1)
```

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned that part of the code. Hence, I assumed he already has it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with `stack` followed by `factorize`:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E']
s = pd.factorize(df[cols].replace('',np.nan).stack())[0]
df['index2_new'] = int(df['index1'].iat[0]) + s
```

---

```
print(df)

  index1 index2 record_type    A    B    C    D    E  index2_new
0    100    100           1  567                             100
1    101    100           2       567                        100
2    102    100           3            567                   100
3    103    101           3            568                   101
4    104    101           4                 568              101
5    105    101           5                      568         101
```

Comment: What does `factorize` do? @anky

Comment: @Vishnudev Its like a string indexer for each unique value

Comment: Ohhh. That is so cool. Learnt something new. Thanks @anky

Comment: @anky Index1 and Index2 are independent